# CKEditor rerenders after every State/ Props Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, ckeditor

currently I am working on a project with Next.js and CKEditor 5. I created an Editor-Component which I want to use on a page. Since I need the value of the input on the parent page, I am using a state and setState as props.

**My Code looks like this:**

*Page:*

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Create() {
    const Editor = dynamic(() => import("../components/MyEditor"), { ssr: false });

    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const handleTextInput = (textInput) => {
        setText(textInput)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div key="editor1div">
                <Editor key="editor1" handleInput={handleTextInput} data={text} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

*Editor-Component:*

```
import Editor from '../../ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor'
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
import '../../ckeditor5-custom-build/build/translations/de';


const MyEditor = (props) => {

    const editorConfiguration = {
        toolbar: {
            items: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <CKEditor
                editor={Editor}
                config={editorConfiguration}
                data={props.data}
                onChange={(event, editor) => {
                    props.handleInput(editor.getData())
                }}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyEditor
```

**My Problem:**
The Editor gets rerendered everytime, a key is hit. That means it also loses focus, which leads to a bad user experience. As far as I understand, setting a key to the editor should prevent rerendering on every props change, but it did not work. As suggested in other similar questions, I tried uuid's v4()-Method as key, but also this did not solve the problem.

**The solution I wish for:**
In the best case, the editor would not rerender on every new char that is entered and just stay the same. Alternatively, if that is not possible, I could also work with a solution in which I manually set the focus to the editor or where the state is not permanently updated, but only on a button click on the Page itself.

Did anybody have similar problems or knows a solution?

Kind regards

Robert

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution my self. For everybody with similar problems: the reason is the dynamic import inside the component. If the dynamic import is outside the component, it works:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useState } from 'react';

const Editor = dynamic(() => import("../components/MyEditor"), { ssr: false });

export default function Create() {

    const [text, setText] = useState("")

    const handleTextInput = (textInput) => {
    setText(textInput)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div key="editor1div">
                <Editor key="editor1" handleInput={handleTextInput} data={text} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer saved my day.